# Why this pattern can't be matched?

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

My code is `{x,y,z}/.PatternSequence[x,y]->t`.I think the answer is `{t,z}`,while the output is still `{x,y,z}`.Why the pattern sequence x,y can't be matched in the list?
Thank for your answer!

Comment: The documentation of PatternSequence mentions that this expression "cannot be the only element of a pattern". Instead use [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html). For instance, `SequenceReplace[{x, y, z}, {x, y} -> t]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
{x, y, z} /. {___, PatternSequence[x, y], any___} -> {t, any}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or in general

```
{a, x, y, z} /. {any0___, PatternSequence[x, y], any1___} -> {any0, t, any1}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]